# Show current time in android smartwatch changing every second or minute

Tags: android, time

I want to create an activity and this activity will show the current time at the top of the screen. I want to show and I need that it changes as time passes by.
I`ve tried this

```
hora=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTime);
String mydate =java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
hora.setText(mydate);
```

Itt shows the current time but it doesn`t change.

Comment: How are you trying to change it?  That code will only set it once.  If you want to change it, you need to call that on a timer.

Comment: @GabeSechan thank you for your response. What’s a timer? Because I’m starting with android and I don’t know a lot.